# Convert HTML ascii codes to corresponding character

Tags: jsp, web, html

how can i convert all html codes in text to corresponding character 
[description contains html code which needs to be decoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coeYz.jpg)

Comment: HTML doesn't use ASCII. It uses Unicode.

Comment: @Blodget No, it uses whichever encoding you tell it to use, whether it be UTF-8, ANSI or ASCII

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you need to decode url-encoded text. If you need to do it in servlet or JSP page, then you can do it by `URLDecoder.decode()`.
Here is API documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)